# Find the joint PDF of X, Y, Z.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, density-function

> Let X, Y, Z be r.v.s such that X ⇠ N (0, 1) and conditional on X = x, Y and Z are i.i.d. N (x, 1).
>
> (a) Find the joint PDF of X, Y, Z.
>
> (b) Find the joint PDF of Y and Z. You can leave your answer as an integral, though
> the integral can be done with some algebra (such as completing the square) and facts
> about the Normal distribution.

Is my reasoning correct?

I did the following:

a) $f(X=x,Y=y,Z=z)=f(X=x)f(Y=y|X=x)f(Z=z|X=x,Y=y)=f(X=x)f(Y=y|X=x)f(Z=z|X=x)=$

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt \pi} e^{-x^2/2} \,  \frac{1}{2\sqrt \pi} e^{-(y-x)^2/2} \,   \frac{1}{2\sqrt \pi} e^{-(z-x)^2/2} \,$$

b) $$f(Y,Z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}( \frac{1}{2\sqrt \pi} e^{-x^2/2} \,   \frac{1}{2\sqrt \pi} e^{-(y-x)^2/2} \,  \frac{1}{2\sqrt \pi} e^{-(z-x)^2/2} \, dx)$$

Comment: Part (a) work is correct, except the last line... there should be no integration. Part (b): integrate the answer for part(a) over $x$ only.

Comment: @Dean Thank you. You can duplicate your comment in answers and I will accept it.

Comment: I think the denominator is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part (a) work is correct, except the last line... there should be no integration. Part (b): integrate the answer for part (a) over $x$
only.